# How do I use If to plot a function conditionally

Tags: plotting, functions, conditional

I am trying to use the `If` so that when the 1st argument is true, it plots a graph of a function and when false, returns 0. I know that the format of an if statement is `If[x, TRUE, FALSE]`, but I don't know how the input works when I want to check the function for x within the `If` expression so that I can graph that function when it is true.

Answer (score 3):

This should show you how to do it.

```
Manipulate[
  If[x, Plot[Sin[2 π t], {t, 0, 1}], 0],
  {x, {True, False}, Setter}]
```

[image: false]

[image: true]

Or, perhaps, this will be closer to the answer you are looking for:

```
With[{x = True}, If[x, Print[Plot[Sin[2 π t], {t, 0, 1}]], 0]]
```

The above will will show your plot, and this will return zero.

```
With[{x = False}, If[x, Print[Plot[Sin[2 π t], {t, 0, 1}]], 0]]
```

In a notebook it looks like this:

[image: notebook]

Answer (score 3):

`Plot` works with logical statements, for instance

```
Plot[If[x>0,x^2,0],{x,-10,10}]
```

Also see `Piecewise` or `Switch` instead of nesting `If`s for multiply defined functions.

Comment: When I try to test the input, it results in an output of the graph even if x is false for some reason.

Comment: Plot f1(x) between x = -10 and x = +10, where f1(x) = +x2 when x is positive, f1(x) = -50 when x is -2 or smaller, and f1(x) = 0 otherwise